# Format and parsing same date provides different result

Tags: java, date, exception, simpledateformat, date-parsing

Could anybody please tell me why I'm getting "10/09/2022" on the console?

```
String sFecha = "10/21/2021";
try {
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
   System.out.println(sdf.format(sdf.parse(sFecha)));
} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
   //Expected execution
}
```

Note: the input string is intentionally wrong - I am expecting the Exception!

Comment: mm is for minutes.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: The last line in the question reads: **Note: the input string is intentionally wrong - I am expecting the Exception!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

The problem you have observed with your code is one of the weird problems that you face with `SimpleDateFormat`. Instead of throwing the exception because of the wrong format,  `SimpleDateFormat` tries to parse the date string erroneously.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sFecha = "10/21/2021";
        try {
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(sFecha, dtf);
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            System.out.println("A problem occured while parsing the date string.");
            // ...Handle the exception
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
A problem occured while parsing the date string.
```

Now, change the format to `MM/dd/yyyy` and you will see that the date string will be parsed successfully.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

#### In case you want to use `SimpleDateFormat`:

Pass `false` to [`SimpleDateFormat#setLenient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) which is set `true` by deafult.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sFecha = "10/21/2021";
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            sdf.setLenient(false);
            System.out.println(sdf.format(sdf.parse(sFecha)));
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("A problem occured while parsing the date string.");
            // ...Handle the exception
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
A problem occured while parsing the date string.
```

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

When you do `sdf.parse()` you convert your text to date with :

```
10 -> days
21 -> month
2021 -> year
```

And 21 as month is converted to 9 (because `21 % 12 = 9`).

Using [`setLenient(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) it will throw an exception instead:

> With lenient parsing, the parser may use heuristics to interpret inputs that do not precisely match this object's format. With strict parsing, inputs must match this object's format.

Answer (score 1):

your format is day/month/year. 21 is not a valid month, It seems it subtracts 12 to get a valid one.

Comment: On the right track, but not the full truth. And then again, accepting to use `SimpleDateFormat` is never on the right track.